# What is the difference between a point and 2 points that are separated by an infinitesimal distance?

Tags: coordinate-systems, infinitesimals

Let's say that over here we have 1 point on some coordinate axis, by itself.

And way over here, we have 2 points that were originally separated by a distance of 1, but we shrunk that distance down to an infinitesimal length.

What then is the difference between these 2 scenarios? Can the 2nd case be treated as 1 point?

Comment: There are calculations where you take an object with positive area or volume and replace it with a "weight" at the object's center of gravity. So there you have an infinite number of points separated by more than infinitesimal distance all being treated as one point. I think the answer to your question depends on _why_ you might want to treat the two points as a single point. It may help if you give more complete information about the context of your question.

Comment: I just wanted to know how professional mathematicians understood this scenario. But the question was inspired by someone explaining to me that if you wanted to find the center of mass of 1 large sphere with a small spherical cavity removed from it, then you can imagine taking the diameters of each and shrinking them down to infinitesimal lengths. Therefore, we could treat the as each being 1 point - their centers. But the more I thought about it the more I couldn't precisely say if this was a valid conclusion.

Comment: After reading your comment, I don't see the connection with the *infinitesimal distance* between two points.

Comment: @whatwhatwhat The explanation given to you seems pretty weird to me...

Comment: Oh, right sorry. I was missing "Imagine the diameters of both the sphere and the spherical cavity. There is 1 point at the end of each diameter because each diameter is a line segment. Now shrink those down to an infinitesimal length."

Comment: It seems that I made a lucky guess about why you might want to treat two points as one. The usual approach in a center-of-mass calculation like that is to go directly from the sphere to a single point, without inserting a "shrinking to infinitesimal distance" step in the middle.

Comment: Your profile suggests that you've studied some calculus. When you do that calculus  with limits, you are essentially making arguments about points "infinitely close" without philosophical handwaving. But thinking about infinitesimal distances often helps your intuition. That's what the physicist in your comment was doing. He did come to a valid conclusion. To prove that you'd write it out with limits instead of infinitesimals.

Comment: The usual situation for something like this is a tangent line: you take secant lines between arbitrarily close but finitely separated points, and as the separation goes to zero you recover a tangent line that only (locally) touches the curve at one point. What we get "in the limit" is now a different sort of object than we used to approximate it: we had *secant* lines (that locally touch the curve in two points) and we got a *tangent* line (that locally touches the curve in one point).

Comment: Or at least this is the standard view. There are nonstandard views and even nonstandard formalisms that use infinitesimals. However, these formalisms don't behave *quite* like you might expect (in particular, there are different formalisms with fundamentally different behavior), and they are not very widely used.

Comment: @whatwhatwhat, you asked above "how do professional mathematicians understand this scenario". The answer is somewhat complex.  In fact, there are two main ways of formalizing this: the A-track and the B-track.  A-track involves an Archimedean continuum containing no infinitesimals; the B-track involves a Bernoullian continuum incorporating infinitesimals. Mathematically speaking the B-track discussions of infinitesimals are equivalent to their A-track paraphrases containing multiple alternations of quantifiers in place of infinitesimals; such paraphrases can be confusing to beginning students.

Comment: @MikhailKatz On the other hand, these alternating quantifiers are exactly what you need for the generalizations of the theory (metric spaces, topological spaces, etc.) and for sharply quantifying the results of the theory (as estimates rather than convergence statements).

Comment: @Ian, this sounds like  a topic for a separate question, which is warmly encouraged. I would like to make two quick observations: (1) generalisations can be handled very well in Robinson's framework, as well; for example, a metric space is complete if and only if every finite point is nearstandard. (2) the point, pedagogically speaking, is not to eliminate alternating quantifiers, but rather to *prepare* the students for them, by means of infinitesimals. Once they understand key concepts like continuity and derivative via infinitesimals, it is easier to explain the *Epsilontik* paraphrases...

Comment: ...since the students already know what those paraphrases are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 5):

The OP seems to be struggling with the notion of limit, when for example a point $A=1$ on the real axis is being approached by a variable point $B=1+\frac{1}{n}$ so that for $n=1$ the point $B$ is located at distance $1$ from $A$ and as $n$ increases, $B$ gets closer and closer to $A$.  To speak loosely, for infinite $n$ it seems that $B$ is infinitely close to $A$ or more precisely the distance between $A$ and $B$ is infinitesimal, but still not zero. Where does the limit come in, and how can you claim that in the limit $A$ and $B$ are the same?

The above is my understanding of the OP's query. The answer is provided conveniently in the [hyperreal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number) framework by the [standard part function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_part_function).  The limit is not the value of $B$ for an infinite index $n$ but rather the standard part thereof.  Only after taking the standard part can one claim that the points are the same.  This is a more direct interpretation of the limit concept than in the epsilon, delta approach where the value of the limit needs to be given in advance, rather than computed directly.

For an accessible introduction see Keisler's [*Elementary Calculus*](https://www.math.wisc.edu/~keisler/calc.html).

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that the answer is in your question. As you are asking about points with an infinitesimal distance between them, you are working within a number system that includes infinitesimals. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal#Number_systems_that_include_infinitesimals) for examples of such number systems. Within such a number system, the points are distinct and are separated by an infinitesimal distance. Their "real number part" however, is the same (much as the "whole number part" of 3.2 and of 3.6 is the same, although as decimals they are different numbers).

Comment: Very good point. You should mention though that not every number system mentioned at wiki includes an analog of the standard part function.

Comment: Good point- hence the quotes around "real number part"..

Answer (score 0):

The elements of sets $X$ which are considered to be "spaces" are called *points*. A point is a point, and is different from all other points in the same space. If a distance function (or: *metric*) $d$ is defined on $X$ then $d(p,q)$ is a *positive real number* whenever $p\ne q$. There is no such thing as "infinitesimally close" points in this context.

On the other hand, if such a point $p$ arises as part of a larger configuration under study you may want to qualify the "standing" of this point within this configuration. An example: The curves $y=x$, $y=x^2$, and $y=x^3$ all intersect the $x$-axis at the single point  $p:=(0,0)$, but the quality of this intersection is different in the three cases. As a mathematician you want to come to grips with this distinction. You then say that $y=x$ has a simple zero at $x=0$, $y=x^2$ a double zero, and so on. After some analysis you will propose the definition that a function $f$ has an $n$-*fold zero* at $x_0$if there is an $a\ne0$ such that
$$f(x)-f(x_0)=(x-x_0)^n\bigl(a+o(1)\bigr)\qquad(x\to x_0)\ .$$
In colloquial language one talks about an $n$-fold tangency between the graph of $f$ and the $x$-axis in such a case. Sometimes one is even inclined to call an (ordinary) tangent point a "double"  point, e.g., in connection with counting the solutions of quadratics.

Comment: You are making the same error as the other responder.  It is inaccurate to say that there are no such things as infinitely close points, unless you specify your context.  It seems unnecessary to copy over the entire discussion in comments below the answer by @5xum, so I will simply refer you to that exchange.

Comment: You are making the same error as the responder 5xum. It is inaccurate to say that there are no such things as infinitely close points, unless you specify your context. It seems unnecessary to copy over the entire discussion in comments below the answer by 5xum, so I will simply refer you to that exchange.  The answer has been deleted by the owner but your *reputation* level should enable you to view it.